# Retrive data from json in Typescript

Tags: arrays, json, typescript

I have an json and i must retrive data in Typescript language. 
This json is made :

{

"tags":[{"name" : "wall", confidence: "0,99"},{"name" : "wall", confidence: "0,99"}]

"requestid" : "ffffff",
"metadata" : "ddddddd"

}
How can i do?

Comment: Please try your best first and if you hit a specific problem then you can ask. We are not supposed to write your program for you. If you need a tutorial on Typescript there are enough online.

Comment: try this  var obj = JSON.parse('{ "name":"John", "age":30, "city":"New York"}');
Then retrive the object property you want